# Java - Can calling System.gc two times release underlying object twice?

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, swig

I have a Java program which calls into my C++ library. JNI-C++ bridging is created using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)

 I am relatively new to Java & trying to understand the behavior of ***System.gc*** & ***System.runFinalization***

 This code below causes a **SIGABRT**, killing my app (2 out of 10 runs)

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        doSomeStuff();
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.runFinalization();
        System.gc();
    }

}

void doSomeStuff()
{
    try
    {
        sampleCppClass cppClass = new sampleCppClass();
        /*
        *   do some stuff with Cpp obj
        */
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.runFinalization();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Whereas this one works fine

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        doSomeStuff();
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.runFinalization();
        System.gc();
    }

}

void doSomeStuff()
{
    try
    {
        sampleCppClass cppClass = new sampleCppClass();
        /*
        *   do some stuff with Cpp obj
        */
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

I know that System.gc() & System.runFinalization() are non-deterministic([Source-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540/when-does-system-gc-do-anything), [Source-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608120/is-java-gc-deterministic) and [Source-3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa284401%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). 

Can it so happen that the System.gc() in doSomeStuff gets executed & free's the obj. 

Later on, the System.gc() in main runs & tries to free  the same obj causing a crash? If this is indeed the case, is there a way to prove it (logs/prints to show the order of object free'ed by gc)? 

This SO post, [explains causes of SIGABRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6)

 Since I am running in release mode, my C++ lib doesnt have any ***assert/abort***. Hence I am concerned about double/multiple free's of the object in consideration.

Comment: No. Because `System.gc()` is only advisory (the JVM may do something, or it may ignore it).

Comment: No, because the object is only released once, and because `System.gc()` may not release it at all.

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch and EJP, Thanks for the response. Can you suggest what else may cause **SIGABRT** in my app? As already mentioned my C++ lib doesnt have **assert/abort** and having only one call to **System.gc()** in main func, seems to solve the issue.

Comment: You seem to have asked the wrong question here. I suggest you start again. But your code doesn't make any sense. You would call `runFinalization()` *after* `gc()`, not before. I would just remove both calls throughout. I haven't used them for decades. I suggest that `SimpleCPPClass` has JNI code in it, and that that is where you should be looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it so happen that the `System.gc()` in `doSomeStuff()` gets executed & free's the obj.

Yes, but it can also happen that it doesn't do anything.

> Later on, the `System.gc()` in main runs & tries to free the same obj causing a crash?

No. Ths is garbage collection, not C++ destruction. It only happens once per object, or indeed never.

The underlying reason for your problem as far as this code is concerned is that you have your `gc()` and `runFinalization()` calls in the wrong order. `runFinalization()` does nothing if there has been no prior GC. It executes the finalizer queue, which is only populated by GC.

So when you do it all twice, only the second `runFinalization()` does anything. This presumably executes a finalizer in your `SampleCPPClass`, which appears to have a bug, evidently in native code.

But as you haven't posted the code concerned it is impossible to comment further.